# "lending support" vs "extending support"

Tags: nuance

I am in a little debate with myself, arguing the difference between "lending support" and "extending support" while trying to write a diplomatic email.

So some people got promoted into highly contested roles and the message was

> Let us congratulate and extend our support to the above members...

But then I thought it may be better to use

> Let us congratulate and lend our support to the above members...

I am not a native speaker but I understand the standalone meaning of "lend" versus "extend", but when used together with "support", "extend" feels like an order to do more work because of these people, whereas "lend" feels like a request and returns/benefits can be expected.

However I am not sure if I am just over-thinking. Can native speakers detect the nuances like I do?

Comment: Fiends, Americans and country persons, lend me your ears. Extend me your years. Lend me your money. Extend me a loan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Extending support" (**professional**)  **>** "lending support".

The promotees may still need (some) support, therefore, in my opinion, [**'extend'**](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/extend) can carry these **two** senses here-

- provide support in scope or range
- continue/prolong the support

*“The support was extended to all citizens”*

> Let us congratulate and **extend** our support to the above members...

[**Lend**](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/lend) support, on the contrary, *is evocative of to "give temporarily".*

(vocabulary.com)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience (native UK), "extend our support" is more common when dealing with non-physical items.

For example, I "lend support by providing equipment" but I "extend my support" in providing congratulations.

You "lend a hand" if someone needs help e.g. to help assist in carrying something heavy.

Answer (score 1):

Lending support is not direct/'longterm' support - for example, http://article.wn.com/view/2013/11/18/Sri_Lanka_Lends_Support_To_Ghanas_Marine_Policing/ - Sri Lanka Lends Support To Ghana's Marine Policing.  Here Sri Lanka has/will not do the Marine policing for Ghana - it may train Ghana coast guards who will be involved in marine policing.  Extending support could be when/if Sri Lanka sends its citizens to do the marine policing in Ghana.

Comment: Interesting insight.

Comment: http://www.colombopage.com/archive_14B/Sep24_1411565656CH.php -  Sri Lankan President extends support to elephant conservation at Clinton Global Initiative meeting .  This is 'global' and 'longterm' issue.

Answer (score 0):

I see "extend" as implying an offer that may not necessarily be accepted. Whereas "lend" implies that we are actually doing it - I would qualify "lend our support", by adding "by (doing) x and y"

In this context I would use extend, with the intent of being ready to provide support as it is needed.